# DB2SQL Trying to create a trigger with function (Calculate days)

Tags: sql, db2

So for now, I created 2 tables, Booking and BookingDetails, I want to create a trigger when I key in the details of BookingDetails it will automatically update totaldays inside the Booking table. Below is my code:

BookingDetails:

```
create table BookingDetail ( 
BD_ID int primary key not null, 
Date_In date, 
Date_Out date, 
BK_ID int, 
Room_ID int,
foreign key(BK_ID) references Booking(BK_ID),  
foreign key(Room_ID) references Room(Room_ID)
)
```

And also Booking

```
create table Booking ( 
BK_ID int primary key not null, 
BK_Date Date, 
BK_TotalDays int, 
BK_PayStatus char(6), 
Cus_ID int, 
Emp_ID int,
foreign key(Cus_ID) references customer(Cus_ID),  
foreign key(Emp_ID) references Employee(Emp_ID)
)
```

With the function and trigger created:

```
create function countdays(t1 date, t2 date)
returns INT
return (timestampdiff(16, char(timestamp(t2) - timestamp(t1))))

create trigger totaldays
after insert on bookingdetail
referencing new as n
for each row mode db2sql
update booking
set bk_totaldays = 
countdays((select date_in from bookingdetail), (select date_out from 
bookingdetail))
where booking.bk_id = n.bk_id;
```

I have no problem executing these syntax, but when I try to input a new record inside Booking Detail to let the trigger triggers in Booking, errors occured, may I ask why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which error? Which OS?

Comment: Using db2 on Windows, the error output "DB2 SQL-Error: -811"

Comment: **WARNING!!** The result of the timestamp subtraction [is an estimate](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscatimedifstmp.htm).  For example, `timestamp('2017-02-01', '00:00:00') - timestamp('2017-01-01', '00:00:00')` yields `100,000,000.000000` (or "1 month"), so would give back **30** days, when the correct answer is **31** days.  _This is almost certainly not what you want._  [Use `DAYS()` for more accurate results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9541845/812837).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the information provided by the SQL error:

```
db2 ? SQL0811
SQL0811N  The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or
  VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.
```

So this part of your trigger expressions returns more than 1 row

```
set bk_totaldays = countdays((select date_in from bookingdetail), 
                             (select date_out from bookingdetail))
```

Fix this to return a single row.

Comment: But how can I fix this by return it to single row so that in my countday functions, are able to calculate by receiving 2 dates as input?

Comment: Well you can receive 2 values but just 1 row - you hav eto correlate the selects to the current insert. At the moment your select date_in from bookingdetail will select as many rows as the bookingdetail table holds. So the function does not know which row / value is the right one.

Comment: From here I try to fix by using this way to select in just 1 line"set bk_totaldays = countdays((select date_in, date_out from bookingdetail where booking.bk_id = n.bk_id))" but it still gave me an error.

Comment: Right track - but bk_id is the primary key of your booking table so there could be still many rows returned as you select the bookingdetails table. Try adding "fetch frist 1 row only"

Comment: I success to execute by adding "Fetch first 1 row only" command, Thanks! But there is a problem here, what if I have multiple values? I tried to insert a few data in but only the first row has the function working while other values remains the same value as first row.

Comment: Ok - well fetch first 1 row is only an example any other extension to your query would do the job if it limits the resultset to a single row - you could select the "last" detail row or the one with the newest timestamp (if it exists). Please do not forget to mark my answer as solution - thanks

Answer (score 0):

@MichaleTiefenbacher is correct about the cause of the error, but he's wrong about what to do about it.  Let's take another look at your trigger again:

```
create trigger totaldays
after insert on bookingdetail
referencing new as n -- wait, what's this?
for each row mode db2sql
update booking
set bk_totaldays = 
countdays((select date_in from bookingdetail), (select date_out from bookingdetail))
where booking.bk_id = n.bk_id;
```

You have a reference to the value you just inserted!  When using `FOR EACH ROW`, the table reference `NEW` refers to the *singular row* just inserted.  So you don't even need to look at the full table, just use what you just worked with:

```
create trigger totaldays
after insert on bookingdetail
referencing new as n 
for each row mode db2sql
update booking
set bk_totaldays = countdays(n.date_in, n.date_out)
where booking.bk_id = n.bk_id;
```

(As I mentioned in my comment to your question, you'll likely want to change how you calculate the days, but that's irrelevant for this)