# SQL JOIN Condition time format error

Tags: join, conditional-statements, ibm-midrange, datetime-format, db2-400

I am working on SQL code for accessing the "Green Screen" AS400 IBM iSERIES using VBA and I am connecting through an ADODB connection (please let me know if you need more information about the connection or the SQL version, I am a beginner in SQL).

Now I have the code running just fine, but I want to add another "AND" condition in the last LEFT JOIN such that the code is only considering the data that exists where [ (PO.STKDT- PO.ACTDT) < 40 ]. In other words, the (stock date) minus the (creation date) is less than 40 days.

So I want to add something like :

```
AND ( date(timestamp((PO.STKDT + 19000000) concat '000000')) - date(timestamp((PO.ACTDT + 19000000) concat '000000')) ) <40
```

The code runs fine without this very condition, but when I add this condition it gives me an error "SQL0181: Value in date, time, or timestamp string not valid".

Any help would be appreciated to resolve the AND condition error

Please note that I have the 'TIMESTAMP' and 'DATE' attached to the STKDT and ACTDT date columns to convert that from format 1171119 to 11/19/2017. And I have a parameter that is correctly pulling column data with this formatting.

Thanks for your help!

Here is my complete code:

```
SELECT X.ITNBR AS ITEM, X.ITDSC AS DESCRIPTION,
X.CRUS AS CREATE_USER, X.INVFG AS INV_FLAG ,
C1.PURPR AS PO_PRICE, C2.STDUC AS STD_COST, 
A.HOUSE AS WHS, A.WHSLC AS WHSLOCATION ,
A.VNDNR AS VENDR,VN.VNAME AS VENDOR_NAME ,
VN.VNAMA, A.MOHTQ AS QTY_ON_HAND,
A.MPUPQ AS QTY_ON_PURCHASE ,A.MALQT AS QTY_ALLOCATED,
(A.MOHTQ+A.MPUPQ-A.MALQT) AS QTY_AVAILABLE,
( (A.MOHTQ+A.MPUPQ-A.MALQT) * C2.STDUC ) AS INV_COST,
K.KIORDCNT AS KB_CARDS, K.KICQTY AS KB_QTY,
K.KICTYP AS KB_TYPE, COUNT( PO.ITNBR ) AS DATA_COUNT ,
AVG(PO.STKPR) AS AVG_PO_PRICE, 
CAST(AVG( date(timestamp((PO.STKDT + 19000000) concat '000000')) - date(timestamp((PO.ACTDT + 19000000) concat '000000')) ) AS DECIMAL(50,2) ) AS AVG_LEADTIME,
SUM(PO.QTYOR) AS ALL_QTY_ORDERED,MIN(PO.QTYOR) AS MIN_QTY_ORDERED,
CAST(AVG(PO.QTYOR) AS DECIMAL(50,2) ) AS AVG_QTY_ORDERED, 
MAX(PO.QTYOR) AS MAX_QTY_ORDERED


FROM SIM.ENT X 
                LEFT JOIN SIM.ITEM A ON (A.ITNBR=X.ITNBR) 
                LEFT JOIN SIM.ITMR C1 ON (C1.ITNBR=A.ITNBR) 
                LEFT JOIN SIM.ITMV C2 ON (C2.ITNBR=A.ITNBR) 
                LEFT JOIN SIM.VENN VN ON (VN.VNDNR=A.VNDNR) 
                LEFT JOIN SIM.KBIM K  ON (K.KIITEM=A.ITNBR AND K.KIHOUSE=A.HOUSE)
                LEFT JOIN SIM.POIT PO ON (PO.ITNBR=A.ITNBR AND PO.HOUSE=A.HOUSE AND PO.VNDNR=A.VNDNR)
                AND PO.STAIC !=99 
                AND PO.ACTDT between '" & Range("AA1") & "' and  '" & Range("AB1") & "' ***AND MYTIMECONDITIONHERE***
            WHERE X.ITNBR != 'TEST%'


GROUP BY X.ITNBR, X.ITDSC,X.CRUS,X.INVFG, C1.PURPR, C2.STDUC 
        ,A.HOUSE, A.VNDNR,VN.VNAME, VN.VNAMA, A.WHSLC
        ,A.MOHTQ,A.MPUPQ,A.MALQT,K.KIORDCNT, K.KICQTY, K.KICTYP`
```

Comment: You cannot use SQL to access a green screen right? You use it to query a database. In the case of IBM i, that database is most likely DB2 for i.

Answer (score 0):

Why convert to timestamp when all you you want to look at is the date?

To convert a numeric CYYMMDD to an actual date, you need to build a string that contains 'YYYY-MM-DD'... so you'd need something like so:

```
select date(                                                
            substring(char(dec(1171120,7) + 19000000),1,4)  
            concat '-' concat                               
            substring(char(dec(1171120,7) + 19000000),5,2)  
            concat '-' concat                               
            substring(char(dec(1171120,7) + 19000000),7,2)  
           ) as theDate                                     
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Rather than converting it inside the statement, build a UDF that converts it.  Or better yet, download such a UDF I recommend [iDate](http://think400.dk/downloads.htm)

Comment: Thanks Charles, I tried the code that you provided .. and it pulled the column data correctly as parameter. But when I used it as a condition it gave me the same error I provided above.

Comment: @MrKen You've probably got a column that contains an invalid date.  Zeros comes to mind ... but 1170229 would fail also.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to examine the DAYS function.  If your original fields are valid date fields, your expression would be as simple as:

```
DAYS(PO.STKDT) - DAYS(PO.ACTDT) < 40
```

Slightly more complicated to first convert via date/timestamp the way you're doing, but should still work. Also see: [Calculating how many days are between two dates in DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538632/calculating-how-many-days-are-between-two-dates-in-db2)

Comment: Thanks Richard, that gave me an error SQL0171: Argument 1 of function DAYS not valid

Answer (score 0):

First I would move your filter conditions for PO out of the join clause (they aren't join criteria), and into the where clause. This is just a semantic thing, and doesn't really affect the query at all. It just makes things easier to understand as all the filter conditions are in one place, and all the join criteria are in another. Then I would use `timestamp_format` to change the numeric date into a `timestamp` value. Then convert the `timestamp`'s into days since January 1, 0001. You can subtract these and compare to 40. Here is your query modified with my suggestions.

```
SELECT X.ITNBR AS ITEM, 
       X.ITDSC AS DESCRIPTION,
       X.CRUS AS CREATE_USER, 
       X.INVFG AS INV_FLAG,
       C1.PURPR AS PO_PRICE, 
       C2.STDUC AS STD_COST, 
       A.HOUSE AS WHS, 
       A.WHSLC AS WHSLOCATION,
       A.VNDNR AS VENDR,
       VN.VNAME AS VENDOR_NAME,
       VN.VNAMA, 
       A.MOHTQ AS QTY_ON_HAND,
       A.MPUPQ AS QTY_ON_PURCHASE,
       A.MALQT AS QTY_ALLOCATED,
       (A.MOHTQ+A.MPUPQ-A.MALQT) AS QTY_AVAILABLE,
       ((A.MOHTQ+A.MPUPQ-A.MALQT) * C2.STDUC) AS INV_COST,
       K.KIORDCNT AS KB_CARDS, 
       K.KICQTY AS KB_QTY,
       K.KICTYP AS KB_TYPE, 
       COUNT(PO.ITNBR) AS DATA_COUNT ,
       AVG(PO.STKPR) AS AVG_PO_PRICE, 
       CAST(AVG(date(timestamp((PO.STKDT + 19000000) concat '000000')) -
           date(timestamp((PO.ACTDT + 19000000) concat '000000'))) 
           AS DECIMAL(50,2)) AS AVG_LEADTIME,
       SUM(PO.QTYOR) AS ALL_QTY_ORDERED,
       MIN(PO.QTYOR) AS MIN_QTY_ORDERED,
       CAST(AVG(PO.QTYOR) AS DECIMAL(50,2)) AS AVG_QTY_ORDERED, 
       MAX(PO.QTYOR) AS MAX_QTY_ORDERED

FROM SIM.ENT X 
    LEFT JOIN SIM.ITEM A ON (A.ITNBR=X.ITNBR) 
    LEFT JOIN SIM.ITMR C1 ON (C1.ITNBR=A.ITNBR) 
    LEFT JOIN SIM.ITMV C2 ON (C2.ITNBR=A.ITNBR) 
    LEFT JOIN SIM.VENN VN ON (VN.VNDNR=A.VNDNR) 
    LEFT JOIN SIM.KBIM K  ON (K.KIITEM=A.ITNBR AND K.KIHOUSE=A.HOUSE)
    LEFT JOIN SIM.POIT PO 
        ON (PO.ITNBR=A.ITNBR AND PO.HOUSE=A.HOUSE AND PO.VNDNR=A.VNDNR)

WHERE X.ITNBR != 'TEST%'
    AND PO.STAIC != 99 
    AND PO.ACTDT between '" & Range("AA1") & "' and  '" & Range("AB1") & "' 
    AND days(timestamp_format(PO.STKDT + 19000000, 'YYYYMMDD')) - 
        days(timestamp_format(PO.ACTDT + 19000000, 'YYYYMMDD')) < 40

GROUP BY X.ITNBR, X.ITDSC,X.CRUS,X.INVFG, C1.PURPR, C2.STDUC 
        ,A.HOUSE, A.VNDNR,VN.VNAME, VN.VNAMA, A.WHSLC
        ,A.MOHTQ,A.MPUPQ,A.MALQT,K.KIORDCNT, K.KICQTY, K.KICTYP
```

Comment: Thanks jmarkmurphy, I just tried my initial working code twice (without adding the 40 days extra condition), one time where I had the condition at the LEFT JOIN and the other time where I have it in the WHERE clause and both gave me different count of 633421 and 246321 respectively. It looks like the WHERE clause limits the results for all the tables not only the PO table. But I want to only include the condition for the LEFT JOIN.